# Shortcode outputting to editor even with return no echo

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm writing a simple plugin that creates a custom post type of quotes then the quotes are output with a shortcode.

Everything works fine except when you save the shortcode on a page, the quotes are output at the top of the editor page.

I do not have any echos anywhere in my code.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the shortcode:

```
function random_quote_generator()
{
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'quotes',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
    );

    $randResults = new WP_Query($args);
    $randQuote = '';
    while ($randResults->have_posts()):
        $randResults->the_content();
        $randQuote .=  "<p>" . the_content() . "</p>";
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $randQuote;
}

add_shortcode('random-quotes', 'random_quote_generator');
```

With the return in there, I'm not sure why it's outputting weird.

Comment: use get_the_content()
as the_content will directly print it out / echo it out

Comment: Thanks, Ralph.  That's exactly what it was.  I appreciate your help!